# problems with one to many, using hibernate in a mixed scala and java project

Tags: java, hibernate, scala, jpa

I am trying to create a hibernate mapping in a project that mixes scala and java

class A is java and is similar to

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "BId")
  private bType b;

  public bType getB() {
    return this.b;
  }
  public void setB(bType b) {
    this.b = b;
  }

}
```

class b is scala and is similar to

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
class B(
  @(OneToMany@field@Transient)(mappedBy = "b") private var _allAs: java.util.set[A] = Sets.newHashSet[A]()
) {
  def allAs:Set[A] = {
    _allAs.asScala.toSet
  }
}
```

so A can have one B but it won't always. B can have many A's but it won't necessarily have any.

what I want is this

- if I get a B I want _allAs to be automatically populated with the set of A's that have   that particular B.

Currently with the setup above everything seems to work accept _allAs never gets populated with anything.

You should also not be able to adjust _allAs through B, if you want to set the b property for an A you have to do it through that A

I am not very familiar with any of these technologies unfortunately so it could be something really obvious that I am missing

edit: also @Transient is there because I really don't need that set persisted in any way I just want to get its population for free which I believe is possible

thanks in advance

Comment: If you mark it as `@Transient`, then it won't get populated from database.

Comment: ok thanks, it dosnt get populated weather transient is there or not unfortunately

Comment: Try printing out the SQL generated by hibernate, and executing it on the DB, see if it returns any results.

Comment: Also, you can try adding `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` to your `@OneToMany`, just to eliminate lazy loading as a cause.

Comment: thanks again, also, I dont want it to get populated from the table B either, in fact there really shouldn't be a column for _allAs in table B at all.  I just want it to look at table A and populate any A objects where A.b equals B.id

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. `A` is the owning side of the relation, you have `@JoinColumn there`, which is a column in table `A`.

Comment: eager fetching does not change anything, I am doing all this so far with an in memory db that is set up automatically by my tests so it might take me a while to figure out how to execute raw sql on it but thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was I needed to refresh the session so that hibernate would fetch the newly updated info, thanks for the help